# How are my windows being tiled? And how can I modify it?

Tags: gnome, compiz, tiling

I can use <kbd>super</kbd><kbd>➡️</kbd> to tile a window on the right half of the screen. (Left arrow to tile on the left, up arrow to maximize; down arrow to restore/unmax)

I thought I was running Compiz, but I disabled Grid in Compiz and my window tiling all still works, which I was not expecting. I think something else is overriding Compiz, but I don't know what it might be and I don't recall having set up an alternative tiling option.

I would really like to be able to tile windows in quarters of a screen as well, but I've been unsuccessful in setting the keyboard shortcut in Compiz that will do that.

[image]

According to the Compiz Settings Manager, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> should place a window in the top right, but the key combination has no apparent effect on anything.

In researching my options I've read a few places that Compiz is incompatible with gnome-shell. I'm running a stock Ubuntu install, and `gnome-shell --version` returns `GNOME Shell 3.36.9` so it seems possible that I'm running gnome shell and so Compiz isn't doing anything and I need an altogether different window tile manager?

I would love some help paving a path to tiling windows in quarter screen increments instead of just half screen increments. I am not sure which questions to ask to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome Shell only supports left and right tiling. Gnome Shell extensions can expand tiling capabilities. [Wintile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1723/wintile-windows-10-window-tiling-for-gnome/) allows to half and quarter tile using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys.