# How do I place windows in Jammy Jellyfish?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz

I thought I had Compiz set up so that <kbd>➡️</kbd> would resize the current window to 50% of the screen and place it on the right half. Ditto for
<kbd>⬆️</kbd><kbd>⬅️</kbd><kbd>⬇️</kbd>.

My keyboard shortcuts stopped working in the upgrade to Jammy Jellyfish and I'm trying to figure out whether I should migrate to a different window management tool, restore Compiz or something else.

What is the intended way to handle window placement in Jammy Jellyfish?

Update: I tried to rephrase my question and surfaced a question from last fall suggesting that perhaps I was running Wintile and not Compiz. [How are my windows being tiled? And how can I modify it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376604/how-are-my-windows-being-tiled-and-how-can-i-modify-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the GNOME documentation:

> You can maximize a window on only the left or right side of the
> screen, allowing you to place two windows side-by-side to quickly
> switch between them.
>
> To maximize a window along a side of the screen, grab the titlebar and
> drag it to the left or right side until half of the screen is
> highlighted. Using the keyboard, hold down <kbd>Super</kbd> and press the <kbd>Left</kbd> or
> <kbd>Right</kbd> key.
>
> To restore a window to its original size, drag it away from the side
> of the screen, or use the same keyboard shortcut you used to maximize.

Source: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-tiled.html.en

If that isn't working, make sure that Compiz isn't overriding anything, check to see if you may have set up Wintile, and in your Settings > Keyboard menu, look at the View and Customize Shortcuts  dialog. There's a section there for Windows.

Comment: That does not work in Jammy Jellyfish

Comment: It does work in Jammy, it's default in GNOME, and Jammy uses GNOME. Also, I run Jammy and verified it works.

Comment: Hmm. Indeed. I need to do more research here.

Comment: This got me on the right track. I added a few additional steps that finally got me sorted.